# Preventing fraud by maintaining a unique hardware id in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

I have an app that uses mobile devices to track real-world activity (gps, motion, etc.).

What I don't want is for scammers to re-use the data with multiple accounts -- that would be "cheating".

With every iOS release Apple makes it more and more difficult to assign a device a unique identifier. I understand and support the privacy issues behind that. On the other hand, I need an *application-specific* unique device identifier, so I can prevent fraud within the application.

This identifier has to survive application updates. On the other hand, all I need is to make it so difficult (that is expensive), that scammers won't find it worthwhile to cheat this way.

Comment: `identifierForVendor` is all you have, may change after a re-install but isn't changed by an update

Comment: and is the identifier explicitly designed for this purpose.